# Get network speed from system files on Linux

Tags: files

At which files should I look to check the (current) download/upload speed? I remember doing so a long time ago. The files I read did not contain the speed directly, but I could calculate the speed with simple arithmetic.

EDIT: I found it, it's `/proc/net/dev`. It shows the sent and received bytes that I just sample every second.

Comment: Can you please clarify whether you want to know the maximum or the instantaneous figures? I can't imagine the latter being available via a file but perhaps the first is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know of a file that can be read to obtain this information.

If you want the maximum connection speed supported by interface `eth0` you can try this as root:

```
ethtool eth0
```

Or

```
mii-tool eth0
```

If you are looking to test your network speed instead, you might be interested in [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426272/how-to-test-internet-connection-speed-from-command-line).  If instead you hope to [actively monitor usage of a network interface](http://kmandla.wordpress.com/2009/04/22/console-network-monitors/) you could use a utility like [slurm](https://computing.llnl.gov/linux/slurm/).